# Migrating to Kotlin - onBind has unresolved reference error in Kotlin class

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm working on migrating some code form Java to Kotlin, and I'm not an expert in either language.

For the most part I've been taking advantage of Android Studio's translate to Kotlin feature and then going through and fixing any bugs.

Right now I'm working on migrating a recycler view, and I have some java code that looks like this:

```
Java

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        ((VideoPlayerViewHolder)viewHolder).onBind(vods.get(i), requestManager);
    }
```

I'm looking specifically at .onBind(vods.get(i), requestManager) above because after the code translated to Kotlin I've been getting an unresolved reference error on onBind.

```
 override fun onBindViewHolder(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, i: Int) {
        (viewHolder as VideoPlayerViewHolder).onBind(vods[i], requestManager)
    }
```

So I'm wondering how to resolve this error. Kotlin didn't seem to handle it automatically. Could someone tell me a little more about what is going on here. Here are the full files also.

Thanks

```
Java


public class VideoPlayerRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<VOD> vods;
    private RequestManager requestManager;


    public VideoPlayerRecyclerAdapter(ArrayList<VOD> vods, RequestManager requestManager) {
        this.vods = vods;
        this.requestManager = requestManager;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        return new VideoPlayerViewHolder(
                LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_video_list_item, viewGroup, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        ((VideoPlayerViewHolder)viewHolder).onBind(vods.get(i), requestManager);
    }
    
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return vods.size();
    }

}
```

```
Kotlin 

abstract class VideoPlayerRecyclerAdapter(
    vods: ArrayList<VOD>,
    requestManager: RequestManager
) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder?>() {
    private val vods: ArrayList<VOD>
    private val requestManager: RequestManager
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(viewGroup: ViewGroup, i: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        return VideoPlayerViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.context)
                .inflate(R.layout.vod_item, viewGroup, false)
        )
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, i: Int) {
        (viewHolder as VideoPlayerViewHolder).onBind(vods[i], requestManager)
    }


    init {
        this.vods = vods
        this.requestManager = requestManager
    }
}
```

```
ViewHolder

public class VideoPlayerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    FrameLayout media_container;
    TextView title;
    ImageView thumbnail, volumeControl;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    View parent;
    RequestManager requestManager;

    public VideoPlayerViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        parent = itemView;
        media_container = itemView.findViewById(R.id.media_container);
        thumbnail = itemView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        progressBar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    }

    public void onBind(MediaObject mediaObject, RequestManager requestManager) {
        this.requestManager = requestManager;
        parent.setTag(this);
        title.setText(mediaObject.getTitle());
        this.requestManager
                .load(mediaObject.getThumbnail())
                .into(thumbnail);
    }

}
```

Comment: Where is the code for the `VideoPlayerViewHolder`? it looks like you don't defined a an `onBind` method in there, but there's no way to tell without seeing the code for that `VideoPlayerViewHolder`

Comment: You're right, it was as simple as I didn't know what was going on. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: the error is gone now that I have the other file implemented

Comment: Yup! that'll do it it looks like. If you want a quick optimization, since at least right now you are only using one ViewHolder. Instead of extending : RecyclerView.ViewHolder in the VideoPlayerRecyclerAdapter, you can pass in your concrete view holder implementation instead, and you can avoid the cast you are doing in the `onBindViewHolder` since you'll have to pass in the concrete implementation

Comment: Sweet, I'll give it a shot.